# Como eu faço para o alert sumir depois que eu exibo ele em uma div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um aplicativo usando JavaScript e JQuery, e quando coloco um alert para exibir um erro em uma div, ele não desaparece, só clicando no x para fechar, gostaria de saber como faço para ele sumir depois de algum tempo.

```
 Código HTML
 <div id="erro" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
                        <button type="button" class="close" onclick="$('#erro').hide()">&times;</button>
                        IP fora da faixa, por favor, digite dois IP's válidos
 </div>


Código JavaScript
$("#erro").show();
```

Comment: Olha, eu acho interessante esperar o usuário clicar no X, assim ele vai estar ciente da mensagem. Se ele se distrair e a mensagem sumir sozinha, pode não saber o que aconteceu. Além do que, se quer que a mensagem suma sozinha, nem precisa muito do botão X.

Answer (score 6):

Para fazer o alert executar por certo período de tempo, use a função setTimeout. Como no exemplo:

```
$("#erro").show();
setTimeout(function () {
  $("#erro").hide();
}, 3000);
```

No caso, esse '3000' significa que ele vai executar por 3 segundos até desaparecer, você pode alterar como desejar.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário usar uma biblioteca (85KB) para tão pouco, 6 linhas de javascript (220 bytes) resolvem.

```js
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("erro").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
    function hide(){
    document.getElementById("erro").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
 <div id="erro" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
                        <button type="button" class="close" onclick="hide()">&times;</button>
                        IP fora da faixa, por favor, digite dois IP's válidos
 </div>
```

Comment: @dvd, é que você não sabe que ele configurou para esvaziar os arquivos armazenados em cache toda vez que fecha o navegador, capiche? Se esse é o seu caso também, posso lhe fornecer a `min` com somente `165 bytes` rsrs